# Best documentation for POSIX file-operations

Tags: linux, unix, posix, standards

I am looking for some comprehensible explanation (rather than technical specification) of what POSIX.1 demands from file-operations syscalls. I would like to design and implement a filesystem in FUSE and I would like to know what would be expected from a POSIX-compliant product. I am also interested in Linux specific syscalls, `ftruncate` has a [significantly more options](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html).

Comment: If your goal is to implement a FUSE filesystem driver, perhaps you should just stick to what the FUSE API and header files provide.

Comment: Aehm.. Check the POSIX specification?

Comment: Functions will not become POSIX compliant merely because they go through FUSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an allegedly well received book on the site as man pages. 
http://man7.org/tlpi/index.html

[image]

(answer to comments: as clearly stated I seek guides, not specs.)